# How to set custom text in titlebar of SSMS(SQL Server Management Studio) 17 using c#

Tags: c#, ssms, titlebar, ssms-2017

Trying to overwrite default title of ssms(sql server management studio) 17.

Tried using below code for setting custom text. This code works fine on ssms 12 but in ssms 17 new title can be seen by hovering ssms icon in taskbar but when ssms 17 window is brought in focus(foreground) old title appears on the application window.

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]   
public static extern Boolean SetWindowText(IntPtr HWND, string Text);

SetWindowText(process.MainWindowHandle, "new ssms title");
```

My main task is to show the new title in SSMS application window. The same title which is shown while hovering the ssms icon in taskbar.

Comment: im guessing the new ssms is wpf based which might not reflect the change.

Comment: tried changing the title of wpf application and it was successful.

Answer (score 1):

The newer SSMS are WPF based. I don't think the win32 API call would have much effect. I would look to solve it by using a WPF call.